# AngularJs ng-grid issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am wondering if it is possible to update grid appearance? 
So I need to update gridOptions, but when I do so, ng-grid does not recognize update(nothing changes). So what is the proper way of updating?

I tried [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/FfnbLhgllUgysN8ZUJZP?p=preview) way among several others, but no luck at all.

If I change the entire $scope.gridOptions nothing happens. Despite the fact, that gridOptions has changed, ng-grid stays the same.